# How to stop a time UILabel from resizing at every time increment?

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsstring, nsattributedstring, core-text

I have a stopwatch feature in my app that uses a centered attributed `UILabel` with a proportionally spaced font to render time. At every time increment the width of the label changes, creating a bouncing effect that looks especially bad at fast speeds. Here is an [example](https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/2s3r1L1s1S1w1K1L1L2t/so%20time%20example.png?v=0fce3396).

How can I fix this?

**iOS 9 UPDATE**

It is now a one-liner:

```
UIFont.monospacedDigitSystemFontOfSize(17, weight: UIFontWeightRegular)
```

Also, last time I tried, the solution below did not work for iOS 9. Wasted quite a bit of time debugging before stumbling on this in the header.

**SOLUTION**

Turned out to be trivial with Text Kit in iOS 7.

Make sure Core Text is imported:

```
#import <CoreText/CoreText.h>
```

Create a setting that converts proportional numbers into monospaced:

```
NSArray *monospacedSetting = @[@{UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey: @(kNumberSpacingType),
                                 UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey: @(kMonospacedNumbersSelector)}];
```

Create a new font descriptor by appending the current one used by `UILabel`:

```
UIFontDescriptor *newDescriptor = [[timeLabel.font fontDescriptor] fontDescriptorByAddingAttributes:@{UIFontDescriptorFeatureSettingsAttribute: monospacedSetting}];
```

Update label's font:

```
// Size 0 to use previously set font size
timeLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:newDescriptor size:0];
```

Comment: Post the relevant code for drawing the text.

Comment: This is a great solution for iOS 9 too where the standard system font has changed to San Fransisco and has proportional-width numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a monospaced font or pass parameters when creating the font which force monospaced numbers:

```
//kNumberSpacingType 6
//kMonospacedNumbersSelector 0
NSArray *setting = @[
                         @{
                             UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey: @(6),
                             UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey: @(0)
                             }
                         ];

return [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:[[self fontDescriptor] fontDescriptorByAddingAttributes:@{UIFontDescriptorFeatureSettingsAttribute : setting}] size:0.0];
```

Answer (score 3):

For future readers:

This is how to enable monospaced numbers on iOS 9 with San Francisco:

```
let originalFont = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17)
let originalFontDescriptor = originalFont.fontDescriptor()

let fontDescriptorFeatureSettings = [
    [
    UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey: kNumberSpacingType,
    UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey: kMonospacedNumbersSelector
    ]
]

let fontDescriptorAttributes = [UIFontDescriptorFeatureSettingsAttribute: fontDescriptorFeatureSettings]    
let fontDescriptor = originalFontDescriptor.fontDescriptorByAddingAttributes(fontDescriptorAttributes)
let font = UIFont(descriptor: fontDescriptor, size: 0)
```

Edit:

Also available on GitHub:
https://github.com/salutis/swift-font-monospaced-digits

Comment: Works in Swift 2.0.  Thanks!  I extended UIFont with a function monospacedFont that contains your code, using self as the originalFont.  That way I can easily get the monospaced version of any label in the app.

Comment: @ObjectiveTC Yep, same here.